# Coinbase Api Key Authentication error Problem

Tags: php, curl, api-key, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I'm trying to check my Coinbase API. I have tried making a bunch of different API keys, keep getting the same error:

this is my Code

```
 <?php

//echo  __DIR__ ;
require_once( __DIR__ . '/CoinBaseApi/vendor/autoload.php');
include "sendMoneyByCB.php";

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\CurrencyCode;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money;

$apiKey='safgzsggzsg';
$apiSecret='NTf4n7CsgWSQWqlxzgr1Igrzsggzd99';

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

echo "$configuration";
?>
```

and the error

```
{"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid api key"}]}
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory: you have `invalid api key`.

Comment: I think that you mixed Coinbase and GDAX API keys. They are different.

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase uses a different API key than Coinbase Pro (GDAX)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).